# What are 4th and 5th digits in linux permission?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I'm trying to understand the permission system of Linux.
I understand the groups:

- owner (u)
- group (g)
- others (o)

  and the permission types:
- read (r = 4)
- write (w = 2)
- execute (x = 1)

*(I've read something about `setuid/setgid` and `sticky bit` and I don't really understand what they are good for.)*

The other thing I don't understand for example in PHP the 5 digits of permission instead of 3: So what does this do?

```
mkdir($directory, 02770);
```

`277` Should mean write perm for the owner, and everything for the group and other users, but what does the first and last digit mean?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Note to those taking information in the question for granted -- that `02770` is NOT `0277` with an extra `0`, it is `0770` with an extra `02000`.  Final paragraph in the question is highly misleading.

Answer (score 2):

More [about setuid, setgid, and sticky bit in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Changing_permission_behavior_with_setuid,_setgid,_and_sticky_bits).

- setuid: the executable file is started with the privileges of the file owner (not the user starting the process).
- setgid: the executable file is started as if the user belonged to the group to which the file belongs.
- sticky: does not allow to delete or rename files in a directory where the user has the write permission, unless the files also belong to the user.

The constant is shown as 5-digit but the first digit is always `0`; it is a convention for octal literals (that is, `010` is 8, not 10). This makes sense because 8-base numbers have digits representing exactly 3 bits, and the permission bits are grouped by 3. (This made a lot more sense on old PDP machines that used octal all around, especially in the machine code presentation, and were the original hotbed of Unix development. On Intel and ARM, hex numbers are common, so octals are not instantly recognized for what they are.)

Comment: Then why do PHP `fileperms` gives me 16895 (dec) as a directory permission? That is 040777 in octal, so it matches the 0777 I defined with `chmod` (for testing), but why would the 5th digit be `4` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

late but here is the answer to your last question:
Bits 11...9 stand for SUID, SGID, Sticky, this info can be easily found.
But there are altogether 16 permission bits. Bits 15...12 code the type of "file": 0001=p=fifo (pipe), 0010=c=character device, 0100=d=directory, 0110=b=block device, 1000="normal" file, 1010=l=link (soft link file), 1100=s=socket
According to this, the "4" simply says "directory".